# M2.3.2 : Guest customers are not redirecting on success page after place order

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

When I placed an order from a guest customer I am not able to get any checkout session data in success action, so that's why user is redirecting on cart page.
Not able to get following

`getLastSuccessQuoteId()`

`getLastQuoteId()`

`getLastOrderId()`

While I am placing an order with logged in customer then I am able to get session data on Success action.

Can any one help me? What could be the issue with guest customer?

Comment: Can anyone suggest what could be the issue?

Comment: Have you install any third party extension into system?

Comment: Yes I have many but I tried to disabled all extension but issue still exists.

Comment: Hi, how you fixed this issue? i am having same issue